# Как конвертировать .py в .exe со своей venv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, virtualenv

Есть небольшой код для работы с DB SQLite. Также в программе используется GUI Tkinter со своими темами. И при этом я работал через venv.

Как мне собрать в одно целое venv и сам код? То есть, я хочу при создании исполняемого файла использовать не просто версию python, а свою виртуальную среду. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если запустить `pyinstaller` с ключами `-D` или `-F`, то при конвертации скрипта `pyinstaller` скопирует все нужные файлы для запуска программы, тем самым вы получите полностью готовую к работе на любом компьютере программу. Разница в ключах в том, что `-D` - собирает все необходимые файлы **в папку с программой**, в то время как `-F` **собирает единый запускаемый файл**, включающий внутри себя все необходимые пакеты, модули и компоненты.

Запускать так:

```
> pyinstaller -D myscript.py
```

или так:

```
> pyinstaller -F myscript.py
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Вроде как рабочий метод, но с моей прогой все не так гладко Там ща проблемы с numpy, которые даже не получается решить понижением версии

Comment: Эммм... Надо гуглить конкретно по `pyinstaller` и `numpy`, так как `pyinstaller` не гарантирует работу со всеми библиотеками.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы использовать виртуальную среду в качестве источника библиотек можно использовать параметр параметр `--paths`. Нужно ввести следующую команду со своими необходимыми параметрами:

```
pyinstaller --paths path\to\venv\Lib\site-packages file.py
```

Вот пример использования:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --paths ^
    "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Новая папка (2)/python librares/venv/Lib/site-packages" ^
    "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Новая папка (2)/python librares/main.py"
```