# Ошибка в pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Сегодня я задавал вопрос [Как конвертировать .py в .exe со своей venv.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154535/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-py-%D0%B2-exe-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-venv/1154568#1154568) Попробовал сделать по решению, которое там скинули, но по непонятной мне причине вылезает ошибка.

### Мой запуск pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller -D -w -i "C:\Users\a-par\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\logo.png" -n "Пробный запуск" LC.pyw
```

### Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import lib
ImportError: cannot import name 'lib' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import) (h:\python380\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\python380\lib\pkgutil.py", line 493, in find_loader
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
  File "h:\python380\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import lib
ImportError: cannot import name 'lib' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import) (h:\python380\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 318, in get_module_file_attribute
    loader = pkgutil.find_loader(package)
  File "h:\python380\lib\pkgutil.py", line 499, in find_loader
    raise ImportError(msg.format(fullname, type(ex), ex)) from ex
ImportError: Error while finding loader for 'numpy.core' (<class 'ImportError'>: cannot import name 'lib' from partially initialized module 'numpy' (most likely due to a circular import) (h:\python380\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\python380\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "h:\python380\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "H:\Python380\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 112, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 732, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 679, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\Мини библиотека 2020.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['LC.pyw'],
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 420, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 309, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 415, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 381, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 795, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py", line 27, in <module>
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 535, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "h:\python380\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 337, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от неё?

---

### Ошибка при понижении numpy

```
Collecting numpy==1.15.4
  Using cached numpy-1.15.4.zip (4.5 MB)
Using legacy setup.py install for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.0
    Uninstalling numpy-1.19.0:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.19.0
    Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\a-par\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nvyhoawv\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\a-par\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nvyhoawv\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cwj75hiz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\include\site\python3.8\numpy'
         cwd: C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvyhoawv\numpy\
    Complete output (252 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


    C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvyhoawv\numpy\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py:477: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
      return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvyhoawv\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvyhoawv\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvyhoawv\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    "svnversion" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
    Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
    "svnversion" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
    Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['H:\\project\\lib\\code\\lc\\mini_library_2020\\env\\lib', 'C:\\']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvyhoawv\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nvyhoawv\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    H:\Python380\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win32-3.8
    creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy
    creating build\src.win32-3.8\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of numpy
  Moving to h:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.19.0.dist-info\
   from H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\Lib\site-packages\~umpy-1.19.0.dist-info
  Moving to h:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\lib\site-packages\numpy\
   from H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\Lib\site-packages\~umpy
  Moving to h:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\scripts\f2py.exe
   from C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-n3wwezo6\f2py.exe
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\a-par\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nvyhoawv\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\a-par\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nvyhoawv\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\a-par\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cwj75hiz\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'H:\project\lib\code\lc\mini_library_2020\env\include\site\python3.8\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1886

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже PyInstaller не дружит с numpy.

numpy понизьте до 1.15.4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374323/2101808

Попробуйте отсюда вручную поставить whl вручную
https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.15.4/#files

Comment: Попробовал понизить, к сожалению выходит ошибка. Ее можно увидеть в самом вопросе

Comment: это нет собранной версии в pypi. нужно поставить компилтор и собрать из исходников.

Comment: пробовали скачать пакет [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)?

Comment: Разрядность библиотеки не совпадает с разрядностью питона или/и пайинсталлера

Comment: @eri, проблема была в кириллице в пути к иконке + иконка была в .png, а надо .ico

Comment: Также после создания .exe прога выдаёт "Не удалось выполнить скрипт pyi_rth_pkgres" и для этой проблемы решение здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815371/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyi-rth-pkgres-and-missing-packages